# Batch script that should set a path variable breaks the string

Tags: windows, batch, environment-variables, path

Im trying to set a user-path variable via setx in a win-batch-script, but it keeps breaking.
The path that I enter...

```
setx path "%path%;%ProgramFiles%\Pseudocode\"
```

...leads to this:

[image: Image of my user-path-vars, where the last one reads just "C:\Prog"]

Sadly, I found nothing online and running the script as an admin also makes no difference.

1. How can I assure, that everyone can download and run this script and still add the whole path?

   or
2. Is there another approach to register a "custom inner console" in cmd (like java, git, vsce, npm) without using path variables?

I have tried to add a powershell-script and execute that one instead of calling `setx`...

```
$newPath = $env:Path + '%ProgramFiles%\Pseudocode\;'

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $newPath, "Machine")

$env:Path = $newPath
```

...but that hasn't worked. (When executing the script, nothing changed.)

Comment: I would start by trimming down your path variables.  Many of which are ***pointless*** to have in your path.  The people responsible these entries either don't understand or don't care.  If *for instance* you do nodejs development from the command prompt, you can eliminate the items in the path, add them to a batch file that launches cmd.exe and work from there.  If you develop all of the nodejs from a single IDE, create a batch file to add the variables and then launch the IDE with that environment.  Trial and error will tell you most of these entries are pointless.

Comment: ***No matter what***, make sure you leave `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32`.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of the %path% variable has a maximum length of 1024 characters, you may have already reached this limit so the rest after C:\Prog got cut off...

Comment: Can I get around that in any way? (When I do it by hand, it works. Just setting it with the batch script fails)

Comment: Yes, by removing something else from the %path% variable something you don't need anymore

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you count the length of the path variable in your registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment) , how many characters are there in there? Easiest is to just copy the value into Notepad++, character count at the bottom.

Comment: I cannot remove other things, because this file may get passed to other users (that I dont know) who have the same problem.

Comment: @xtay2 Maybe by using Powershell, you can use powershell form inside your batch script...

Comment: @MiG 1018 Chars

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: When I'm testing this on my own machine I get the message *"WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters."* That's presumably your limit, which explains the cut off at the end.

Comment: @RicardoBohner Win11

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion about this see it that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10

Comment: I've read the whole discussion and tried different approaches including powershell scripts. None of them worked :(

Comment: If you can add which of those approaches you've tried (and how exactly, including results) to your original question, maybe someone can figure out what you've missed :)

Comment: +1 because this answer is correct (well, it got the size wrong) and really does not deserve a -1.

Comment: @LPChip We have a down voter secret agent walking around and unfortunately he doesn’t comment on anything that returns in useful quality.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Comment: @LPChip I understood. Because it doesn’t happen to him so he does it to others, lol

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the maximum length of how many entries you can have in the PATH environmental variable.

Keep in mind that the only thing the PATH environmental does, is allow you to run a command from anywhere and it will search for those folders too.

You can shorten paths by finding out what the old style dos name is, and then edit the path and change them. This will work on your system, but will become a problem on other systems. In case you want to do it on your system, here's how you find out.

```
cd /d c:\
dir /x
```

This will show you something like this:

```
C:\>dir /x
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1C0C-DB56

 Directory of C:\

07-12-2019  10:14    <DIR>                       PerfLogs
20-02-2022  15:10    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
08-03-2022  17:47    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
09-03-2022  14:53    <DIR>                       temp
14-11-2021  19:27    <DIR>                       Users
04-03-2022  21:11    <DIR>                       Windows
               0 File(s)               0 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  509.363.785.728 bytes free

C:\>
```

You can substitute the full `C:\Program Files (x86)\...` by `C:\PROGRA~2\...` in all your path rows, and other folders with a space or that are longer than 8 chars will also have a shortened name.

Once done, you can add your entry to the Path, although it is recommended to use the short version, which would probably be: `C:\PROGRA~1\Pseudo~1`

Now, that said... given that path is only used to be able to run a program from anywhere so it searches for that path, you do not need to actually include entries in the path environmental if you always reference to the full path of your program. That could be done such as: `%ProgramFiles%\Pseudocode\myprogram.exe`

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. But my script has to work on other machines which I know nothing about, so I don't think that selective shortening is an option.

Comment: So the question becomes, is it really necessary to have the path environmental variable updated? Because all it does is make it possible to call the executable from anywhere as if you don't know the path, but you always know the path anyway.

Comment: I'm writing a interpreter for a programming language and my goal is, that the user can just build/format/run a project with the command ´pseudocode "path/of/project"´ from cmd. It shouldn't be necessary to write out the %ProgramFiles%\Pseudocode part every time, and from my experience, other compilers (java, js, haskell, prolog) use the same mechanic.

Comment: You can also create a different mechanic. Create a file `c:\windows\pseudocode.cmd` and inside place `start %ProgramFiles%\Pseudocode\pseudocode.exe %1 %2 %3 %4` and you don't need to modify the path.